# Internet Explorer 8, Firefox, Office, and other programs are not displaying correctly

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, internet-explorer-8, microsoft-office-2007

I'm trying to help my father with his computer, he had some viruses that were removed by a local company, but since their cleanup everything has been displaying very weirdly. Here are some examples: [image: Office] [image: Firefox]

Notice how in Word the Office Button is completely discolored, and in FireFox, the images are not only discolored, but the blue boxes below the image should have arrows in them and look more like this: [image]

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the colour depth is wrong, check your display settings, and if that dosen't help reinstall the graphics driver- looks like the colour depth is set to 16 bit or less

Just to be safe its not a system file, try running sfc /scannow from cmd. You will need a windows cd for the same version for this - so that you can rule out any damage to system files.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the color depth is 32 bit as it should be. I can try re-installing the graphics driver though

Comment: it definately *looks* like colour depth to me. that very much looks like the failsafe that's used when there's no driver that windows can recognise, and it falls back to vesa mode. adding another possible fix

Answer (score 1):

Try to log on with another user, and look. In my case, the problem was with the user profile.
I solved this by deleting and creating another user profile.

Answer (score 0):

As per your problem about the Display, It may be of problem of Display Driver. But you mentioned that you had problem of viruses and some local company clear it. Just try to Repair your XP. As per my knowledge it will solve your problem.but Repair mode will only work when you were using XP SP 2. So try that one.

I am giving you the video link of youtube for the Help:

http://youtu.be/KNOQ0sCYY8s

I am giving you the Images link for the Help:

http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/topic/138-how-to-repair-windows-xp/

Answer (score 0):

This is because Windows XP is configured to use high contrast.

To disable it open up *Accessibility Options* from the Control Panel, go to the *Display* tab and disable the **Use High Contrast** option.

Comment: Alas I cannot tell if this is the answer or not. We ended up just blowing away the computer and reinstalling (it was having some other issues)

Comment: No worries. As you can imagine it was rather obscure to work out it was the source of the issue. It also explains when SJTGT solved it with another user profile because it is a per user setting.